# Facebook business page with no real person profile

Tags: facebook, social-networking

Hi i want to make a business page but no releated to my facebook profile so if i make a profile with no real human name, will i have an problem? Does facebook go to delete it?
Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about use of facebook.com and should be directed to webapps.stackexchange.com or facebook's help center

Answer (score 0):

Creating fake accounts are against Facebook User Policy and we find the account it will be deleted together with the page.